# Why can't I kill a process in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script:

```
firefox <url>
sleep 5
kill -9 $(pidof firefox)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I bet Firefox doesn’t return so the rest of your script doesn’t run.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Doesn't return what? A PID?

Comment: Like doesn’t return at all, blocks while Firefox runs... also how do you get the pid?

Comment: @GradyPlayer It does. I get the pid with the pidof command

Comment: Do not use `-9`. It is harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run `firefox` like that on my Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) system the firefox command runs as a foreground process.  That means that the `sleep 5` command never gets to run.

You need to put the Firefox process into the background like this:

```
firefox <url> &
sleep 5
kill -9 $(pidof firefox)
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my life! I have been trying to find the answer for hours!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the pid in a variable, for a pure shell solution.

```
firefox <url> & pid=$!
sleep 5
kill "$pid"
```